# jQuery script for Wordpress ONLY works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var now = new Date;
    $('.code-date').text(function (i, v) {
        if (now > new Date(v)) {
            $("#web-btn").text('Register Now');
        } 
    });
});
```

So what I'm trying to do is after the event happens the text in the button changes to view archive

Here's a link to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SCATORY/fs2hom47/

Comment: you should add "console.log" inside you script, to see what happens...

Comment: For jQuery in Wordpress try changing the `$` with `jQuery`, so from  `$(document)` to `jQuery(document)` and so on :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski But Why should it work in Chrome but not on other browsers then?

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski this kind of stuff often differs depending on your browser... Each browser implements its own behavior in case of "unconstistant code"...

Comment: @Random But does this match to our example here? Even in jsfiddle, which is not in a Wordpress environment, where you often have to use jQuery because of the ´jQuery.noConflict()´, it is not working. Also we know that the ´$´ normally works in any other browser too. But in this fiddle it is only working within Google Chrome.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski it works in my fiddle....its weird....i'll try fiddle in another browser

Comment: @JasonSprague yeah it works in fiddle in chrome,but not in other browsers, as you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Ah, didn't saw that one. Well the problem is your date format.
When you are calling `new Date(v)`, `v` is an invalid date format and is not accepted as a date string.

In your div .code-date the date is written as `10-14-15` and it represents an invalid date. If you use the format as you have it in .news-date `Oct 14, 2015` it will work as it should everywhere, not only in `chrome` .

Read more here : [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Here is a working example :)

```js
 $(document).ready(function($) {
   var now = new Date();
   $('.code-date').text(function(i, v) {

     if (now > new Date(v)) {
       $("#web-btn").text('Register Now');
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h1 class="news-section-title">
                <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg"></i> Webinars
              </h1>


  <!-- the loop -->
  <article class="news-item">
    <span class="news-date">Jun 15, 2016 | 11:00 AM</span>
    <h2 class="news-title"><a target="_blank" href="http://xtalks.com/EvriBeat-Dynamic-Electrocardiography.ashx" class="news-link">EvriBeat – Dynamic Electrocardiography <div class="code-date" style="display: none;">Jun 15, 2016</div></a></h2>
    <div class="news-excerpt">
      <p>BioTelemetry Research’s exclusive offering, EvriBeat, an advanced alternative method&nbsp;to Thorough QT studies for assessing cardiac safety in early human trials.</p>
    </div>
    <!--1465948800--><a target="_blank" href="http://xtalks.com/EvriBeat-Dynamic-Electrocardiography.ashx" id="web-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm download-link">
   
      View Archive</a>
  </article>
  <article class="news-item">
    <span class="news-date">Oct 14, 2015 | 11:00 AM</span>
    <h2 class="news-title"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.xtalks.com/New-Phase-I-Cardiac-Safety-Paradigm.ashx" class="news-link">Dynamic Repolarization Analysis:  A New Phase I Cardiac Safety Paradigm<div class="code-date" style="display: none;">Oct 14, 2015</div></a></h2>
    <div class="news-excerpt">
      <p>BioTelemetry Research is proposing a service offering for evaluation of cardiac repolarization in early human trials, novel to the industry, called Dynamic Repolarization Analysis.</p>
    </div>
    <!--1444780800--><a target="_blank" href="http://www.xtalks.com/New-Phase-I-Cardiac-Safety-Paradigm.ashx" id="web-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm download-link">
   
      View Archive</a>
  </article>
  <article class="news-item">
    <span class="news-date">Jun 24, 2015 | 11:00 AM</span>
    <h2 class="news-title"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.xtalks.com/Medical-Imaging-Oncology-Clinical-Trials.ashx" class="news-link">Medical Imaging: Maximizing Efficacy and Safety in Oncology Clinical Trials<div class="code-date" style="display: none;">Jun 24, 2015</div></a></h2>
    <div class="news-excerpt">
      <p>In this free webinar, industry experts Sandra Chica, MD and Polina Voloshko, MD aim to describe novel medical imaging approaches and methodologies to help sponsors maximize clinical trial efficiency along the development pathway.</p>
    </div>
    <!--1435104000--><a target="_blank" href="http://www.xtalks.com/Medical-Imaging-Oncology-Clinical-Trials.ashx" id="web-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm download-link">
   
      View Archive</a>
  </article>
  <article class="news-item">
    <span class="news-date">Apr 28, 2015 | 11:00 AM</span>
    <h2 class="news-title"><a target="_blank" href="http://xtalks.com/Evaluation-of-Atrial-Fibrillation.ashx" class="news-link">Evaluation of Atrial Fibrillation and Other Arrhythmias within Clinical Trials and Clinical Practice<div class="code-date" style="display: none;">Apr 28, 2015</div></a></h2>
    <div class="news-excerpt">
      <p>In&nbsp;this free webinar learn&nbsp;how big data is transforming cardiac research. Presented by&nbsp;Polina Voloshko, MD, Chief Medical Officer, BioTelemetry Research, and Wayne M. Derkac, MD, Vice President of Medical Affairs, BioTelemetry.</p>
    </div>
    <!--1430179200--><a target="_blank" href="http://xtalks.com/Evaluation-of-Atrial-Fibrillation.ashx" id="web-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm download-link">
   
      View Archive</a>
  </article>
  <!-- end of the loop -->

</div>
```

Comment: THAT'S WHAT IT WAS! Huge thanks and I owe you a coffee